# javascript file size and page loading times

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, caching

I'm making an ASP.NET web forms web app. I've just started with the client side scripts. I'm planning to put quite a lot of JavaScript code in a file that will be loaded on each page. I want to know some general guidelines about when to start worrying about the size of the file, in consideration of the users and their page loading times.

The users will mostly be using Internet Explorer 7 and 8, but I suppose the script still will be cached after the first visit? If not, is there any way to make IE cache the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They'll be cached, like you suppose, after the first visit, so you don't need to worry unless it actually becomes an issue.